# replace "." by NA in a data frame where "." is also used as decimal

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I got a data frame where "." is used both as decimal marker and alone as NA.

```
A    B    C    D
1    .  1.2    6
1   12    .    3
2   14  1.6    4
```

To work on this data frame I need to obtain:

```
A    B    C    D
1   NA  1.2    6
1   12   NA    3
2   14  1.6    4
```

How should I deal to keep decimals but transform alone "." in column C?

Here is the data in a reproducible format:

```
data <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 2L), B = c(".", "12", "14"), C = c("1.2", 
    ".", "1.6"), D = c(6L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: the answers are good , but if you can use `na.strings="."` upstream when you use `read.csv()` or `read.table()` to get the data, that would be even better ... (oops, now I see that @AnandaMahto mentioned this already in his answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type.convert` and specify `"."` as your `na.string`:

```
df <- data ## Create a copy in case you need the original form
df
#   A  B   C D
# 1 1  . 1.2 6
# 2 1 12   . 3
# 3 2 14 1.6 4

df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), na.strings="."))
df
#   A  B   C D
# 1 1 NA 1.2 6
# 2 1 12  NA 3
# 3 2 14 1.6 4
```

Note that the argument is `na.strings` (with a plural "s") so you can specify more characters to be treated as `NA` values if you have any.

Also, the actual answer to this question *might* be to simply specify the `na.strings` argument when you are first reading your data into R, perhaps with `read.table` or `read.csv`.

Let's replicate the process of reading a csv from within R:

```
x <- tempfile()
write.csv(data, x, row.names = FALSE)

read.csv(x)
#   A  B   C D
# 1 1  . 1.2 6
# 2 1 12   . 3
# 3 2 14 1.6 4

read.csv(x, na.strings = ".")
#   A  B   C D
# 1 1 NA 1.2 6
# 2 1 12  NA 3
# 3 2 14 1.6 4
```

Comment: na.strings argument in read.table is probably the simplest/shortest/most elegant solution!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data frame is `data`:

```
data[data == "."] <- NA
```

should work. Or:

```
data <- sapply(data, as.numeric)
```